# Xamarin Forms Android Serial Communication to ESP32

Tags: android, xamarin, serial-port, esp32

I have tried to research a solution to my problem, but I think I lack the mental capacity to fully solve it from the examples I've found!

I have a project split into 2 halves. An ESP32 to read a RFID and iButton and an android front end to run on a kiosk.

I have the ESP set to spit out the serial numbers of the device connected/tapped and this works nicely on a windows pc with system.io.ports. What i thought would be easy is actually frustratingly difficult.

I've used the usbmanager to identify the USB devices and this works:

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting USB");
        var DeviceList = manager.DeviceList;
        foreach (var device in DeviceList.Values)
        {
            var Class = device.Class;
            var DeviceClass = device.DeviceClass;
            var DeviceId = device.DeviceId;
            var DeviceName = device.DeviceName;
            var DeviceProtocol = device.DeviceProtocol;
            var DeviceSubClass = device.DeviceSubclass;
            var Type = device.GetType();
            var ManufacturerName = device.ManufacturerName;
            var ProductId = device.ProductId;
            var ProductName = device.ProductName;
            //var SerialNumber = device.SerialNumber;
            var VendorId = device.VendorId;
            var Version = device.Version;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DeviceName + " " + VendorId);   
        }
```

However, how do I connect to one of the serial ports? namely one called /dev/bus/usb/006/002 4292 and read the string from it?

I've looked at several nuget libraries, but I'm struggling to get my head around these.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me out! I'd rather not go back to using a windows PC in the kiosk. But serial coms on windows are so simple - although windows does have plenty of its own problems :)

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: For possible solution see: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

Comment: yes i found that one, I thought that was for android studio rather than xamarin forms? I found some wrappers, but I can't manage to get it to read a string from the serial port

Comment: Ah okay, yes its for Android Studio so you'll need to wrap the code/use native library for Xamarin. I think there is a sample app (or two) in the project so at worst you can use that Java/Android app to verify that some communication is occurring with your hardware. If you are running custom hardware then editing your post with details may help.

Comment: ok, i kind of made some progress.....  but now i'm having a whole other problem. I've set the ESP32 to output !HELLO WORLD@. In putty this works as it displays each received string on its own line. But with the usb serial driver it splits it up like 
!
H
ELLO
WORLD
@

Do you have any tips on this?